# Is it acceptable to begin a declarative sentence with "Am"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, colloquialisms, sentence-starts, subject-drop

I want to know firstly if it's grammatically correct to start a declarative sentence with "Am". For example:

> Am excited about the game today.

Secondly, if it is grammatically incorrect, then I wanted to ask how much "head room" there is for the above usage. I can't think of an example now, nor find one here at english.stackexchange. However I imagine there are usages of the english language that grammatically are illegal, yet have somehow become accepted as colloquial or idiomatic perhaps.

Comment: You're probably hearing people say _I'm_, with an accent that makes the "I" part inaudible to you. _I'm_ is vastly more common in speech than _am_. That's in speech. In writing, everything depends on the context, and everybody makes up their own rules for infrml wrtng.

Comment: I've noticed people from Africa start sentences this way and claim to be from US cities. It is a pre cursor to possible money scam.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some languages are subject-drop languages, but English is considered a subject-obligatory language. The sentence as it stands is non standard. It's the type of telegraphic language you might see in a text message.

Comment: +1 @Brett. Ah interesting, I din't know about that "subject-obligatory" rule. I think that's the clincher!

Comment: Also social networking sites, forums, etc., normally "auto-preface" every comment with the username. So when I see *FumbleFingers* appearing on a chat log in front of whatever I type, it looks "grammatical" to omit **"I"**, switch to third person, and enter a comment like **thinks the moon is made of green cheese**.

Comment: @brett: Hey, what do you think of Henry's answer below and my comment to him? It's interesting that with "Am", there is not ambiguity as to what the subject pronoun should be...?

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with Henry.

Comment: Never implied? No. Not true.

Comment: @Robusto: What are you referring to?

Comment: @BrettReynolds: Don't know?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thinking of the old "`/me`" oft-used in old forums?

Comment: @Pacerier: Certainly not! Until I just looked it up I didn't know anything about **/me**, and even now I'm not sure how *useful* it is. Sometimes I might wrap an "action" statement in angled brackets and discard the [pro]noun subject that would represent **\me** in certain contexts. **<Sighs wistfully, recalling the early days of Internet chat>**

Answer (score 15):

There is a style of English speaking which drops subject pronouns, which I associate (perhaps wrongly) with Colonel Blimp-type figures.  Something like:

> Went up to town this morning.  Met Caruthers at the club. Just got back from Africa.  Ate a well lubricated lunch together for old times' sake. Am now coming home by train.

It is not standard English, and is prone to ambiguity.  But it exists.

Comment: +1 ah ha! interesting. I'm not very grammatically knowledgable and so didn't pick up that it was all about the dropping of the subject pronoun. So with that now established, I guess starting a sentence with "Am..." is as acceptable as starting one with "Went...". However I'd say "Am..." is a little different no as there is no ambiguity?

Comment: @andy: I would seriously suggest you just ignore this style. As Henry says, it's non-standard. Using it most likely won't give people the impression you have extensive knowledge of English and can fluently use all variations - it'll make them think you haven't been well taught.

Comment: "You're late!" ... "Am not!"

Comment: @GEdgar, Good counter example.

Comment: @Henry, Need some context on this. What's with this "*Colonel Blimp*"?

Comment: @Pacerier https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonel_Blimp and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_and_Death_of_Colonel_Blimp

Answer (score 8):

It’s quite normal to drop the subject pronoun in contexts where brevity is important. It is certainly a practice found in emails and texting, but it was previously found in their predecessor, the telegram, and many people drop the subject pronoun when taking notes. It is also dropped in quite formal prose to avoid repetition, as in, for example, *I went to New York last week and am going again tomorrow.* It is a form of ellipsis, and should not be considered ungrammatical.

Comment: Re "*when taking notes*", any source on this?

Answer (score 2):

Scottish English has a common replacement *Am* for *I am:*

> Am going to be late tonight.

This can be compared to the [contraction of the negative form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amn%27t#Amn.27t), which doesn't drop the *I:*

> I amn't going to be late tonight.

Comment: True, but maybe worth noting that in this case it's not that the pronoun 'I' is dropped or silent. The Scottish first person singular nominative pronoun is pronounced as 'Ah' and spelled either "Ah or "A". So it's not that the subject is dropped, it's just a contraction similar to Standard English "I'm". You could also write it as "Ah'm going to be late tonight".

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to say "I am...." or your sentence is missing a subject.  In other languages, such as Greek, you might say "Ego..... "  but that translates to "I am;" in that case there is an understood first-person subject caused by the conjugation of the verb "to be."

This is not, however, acceptable in English.

Comment: +1 @ncmathsadist: hey, yeah I understand "I am" is the correct form, but was wondering on the acceptance of "Am". As you say, in greek "Ego..." is accepted because there is an understood first-person subject. However, wouldn't you say that "Am..." also suggests a clear first-person subject?

Comment: But, according to standard English usage, you are omitting the subject. The "am" is a verb in the predicate.

Comment: `Ego` doesn't mean `I am` by the way.  `Ego` just means `I` in both Greek and Latin.  `Ego eimi` is `I am` in Greek, and `sum` is `I am` in Latin (sum, es, est, sumus, estis, sunt).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what context you're seeing people use this, but I would guess that it's internet or texting related. If so, then it's just typical modern-day internet prose (i.e. the continued downward spiral of the English language).

Technically, it is not grammatically correct. A sentence should have a subject and a verb (at least that was how I was taught). I certainly wouldn't use it in any formal writing.

Comment: okay, that actually makes sense because i have not come across it in any formal writing. it is mostly internet and texting related

Answer (score 0):

I believe some people find it easier to (only) use "am" in cases where they have already used the subject pronoun and have to use it a second time in the same sentence. **Example**: "I went on maternity leave on December 1st, and am not returning to work." ...It would just save you the having to specify that **YOU** did something, and (again) **YOU** will (or are) doing something as a consequence of. - However, (to me) it would feel more (grammatically) correct to use the subject pronoun as many times as you have to.  **Example**: "I went on maternity leave on December 1st, and  I am not returning to work."