# What’s the subject?

Tags: subjects

What’s the subject for the verb *suppose*?

> Now, yer mum an’ dad were as good a witch an’ wizard as I ever knew. Head boy an’ girl at Hogwarts in their day! Suppose the myst’ry is why You-Know-Who never tried to get ‘em on his side before. . . probably knew they were too close ter Dumbledore ter want anythin’ ter do with the Dark Side.

Comment: If you have tried to find an answer to the question, let us know.

Comment: Related: [Is it acceptable to begin a declarative sentence with “Am”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58285/is-it-acceptable-to-begin-a-declarative-sentence-with-am) and the questions linked from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subject of "suppose" is **"I"**. It's been elided from the sentence. This is quite common in informal speaking and even in writing. **"Hope this helps"** = **"I hope this helps"**.

Comment: Yes, while reading Harry Potter, I've gotta try to find out what the subject of this verb many times. Especially in Hagird's words, i can hardly find them.