# "I am" vs "am" - When should they be used in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-drop

So often, I find people using *am* instead of *I am*, for example,

> - am going to work
> - am okay
> - am sleeping

Is this grammatically correct and when should *am* be used in a sentence if it is not preceded by *I*?

Comment: Am pretty sure this question has been [asked before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58285/is-it-acceptable-to-begin-a-declarative-sentence-with-am) (several times, in fact — look at the related questions there).